How can I inject a bean into an @InboundChannelAdapter?
Considering that a method annotated with @InboundChannelAdapter can't accept any parameters for some reason, how can I inject a bean? The channel property of this annotation already references a bean, so why can't I reference any other bean?
For my specific case, I'm using spring-integration-aws to poll a S3 bucket. The InboundChannelAdapter is declared as follows:
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "s3Channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> s3InboundStreamingMessageSource() {
        S3StreamingMessageSource messageSource = new S3StreamingMessageSource(template(s3client()));
        // more config here
        return messageSource;
    }

What bothers me is that I must call the s3client() method to get a S3Client instance, but I'd rather obtain it as a bean since it can be shared.
How do I achieve that?

Just tested it and that works well:
    @Bean
    S3Client s3Client() {
        return S3;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100"))
    public S3StreamingMessageSource s3InboundStreamingMessageSource(S3Client s3Client) {
        S3SessionFactory s3SessionFactory = new S3SessionFactory(s3Client);
        S3RemoteFileTemplate s3FileTemplate = new S3RemoteFileTemplate(s3SessionFactory);
        S3StreamingMessageSource s3MessageSource =
                new S3StreamingMessageSource(s3FileTemplate, Comparator.comparing(S3Object::key));
        s3MessageSource.setRemoteDirectory("/" + S3_BUCKET + "/subdir");
        s3MessageSource.setFilter(new S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "streaming"));

        return s3MessageSource;
    }

Pay attention how I inject S3Client as a bean method argument.
Right, my IntelliJ IDEA complains:

But that's because it is only aware of the @InboundChannelAdapter, but doesn't take into account that there is a @Bean as well.
So, in other words, any @Bean method definition works as it is expected by Spring Framework.

Interesting! I should have tried it myself instead of trusting the warning... Anyway it does work as I expected it to work, thanks. If you don't like warnings you can still add @SuppressWarnings("SpringIntegrationMethodEndpointInconsistency") to the method.

Good. So time for this then to let community know that there is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers !
